# .NET Core Launch (console) (Debugging) how can I get it?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

[.NET framework (recommended) not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLoFC.png)

[.NET core, what I am trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F961m.png)png

I am trying to enable the debugger, but for some reason the .NET framework that is system recommended isn't working. And I don't have the .NET core debugger from some reason, I installed the .NET SDK 6.0 x64. I pretty much installed all of the .NET extensions [.NET extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71XAs.png) And I still can't find the .NET Core debugger. If anyone has a link to a video on how to install send it please.

Comment: It also sounds like you're mixing up .NET Framework and .NET Core - they are two different SDKs. If you are currently targeting .NET Framework and you want to target .NET Core, you might be able to do that.

Comment: @Luke I fixed the link, OP was missing file extension =)

Comment: Based on screenshots it seems that you are trying to debug C# app using VS Code on Mac OS. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks @GuruStron! I've edited my comment as a result.

Comment: You will have to uninstall everything except C# extension from Microsoft to rule out all conflicts. Then when you open a .NET Core project folder, it will download vsdbg and ask if you want to add the proper debugging support files (like `launch.json`). Only from then on you can debug a project properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys if anyone meets this problem, I just had to repair the .NET files from the setup file that you download. And restart Visual Studio. Thanks for the help anyways.